# surveymonkey popup not showing

Tags: surveymonkey

I setup a wordpress blog and wanted to add a popup from surveymonkey. To simply test if it gets loaded I added the script within the `footer.php` before the closing body tag. Then I reloaded the page but the popup didn't appear, I tried the same with an empty html page where it did work.

Then I compared the developer console and it seems that not everything gets loaded. For some reason after the object has been loaded nothing else gets loaded. I even tried to add the script to another project (not wordpress) but it doesn't work either.

I also tried to setup a new collector and added the script tag again to my project. The popup has been loaded, but after I reloaded the page the same happens as before. It does work though when I use an embedded survey, instead of a popup survey.

Here are my results on firefox:

**Any page**
[image]

**Empty page**
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add in the **edit** This is the correct answer but also I wanted to give context to why the default nature SurveyMonkey creates here is not good. If the end user activates the survey a single time the fact that it would not open again makes no sense and is a poor user experience.

The user would never know, if they closed the survey prematurely, that there was no reason that the activation of the survey could not be completed again.

SurveyMonkey allows for the survey to be taken again until it is completed and then the survey would explain to the user they have already completed the survey. This is a good user experience and sufficient.

***End edit

Just chiming in here, despite this being an old question. The previous answer is absolutely correct as the Survey Monkey popup will only display once and there's nothing you can do via the Survey Monkey interface to get it to show multiple times in a single browser session.

However, you can resolve this issue by adding the following JS above your Survey Monkey JS code:

```
<script>document.cookie = 'smcx_0_last_shown_at=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';</script>
```

This code clears a cookie created by the Survey Monkey pop up that keeps track of when it was last displayed, so it'll display every time the page is refreshed without the need to end the current browser session.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I am posting a reply in case it helps someone else. It appears that Survey monkey limits the number of time the pop up shows to once per browser session.

I have tested in Chrome, Firefox & Edge and I was able to reproduce this behavior very consistently.

If either the embed or the pop has shown up once, the pop up will not show up a second time until you either close and re open the entire browser, or load the page in incognito/private browsing mode. But you will still need to close and re open the private/incognito browser window/tab each time you reload the page containing the pop up.

As of yet, I have not found an option within the Survey Monkey interface to disable this behavior for the pop up survey. Note that the embed survey does not suffer from this.